# SQL subquery with average of 3 top values in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I need a little help to solve a query to count patients (ID) who have the average of the 3 last diastolic tension (TAD) < 90.

I've tried several type of nested subqueries with different errors.

This is my last version I've done:

```
SELECT CENTRO, COUNT ( DISTINCT ID )
FROM
(
    SELECT PAC.CENTRO, PAC.ID, T.TAD
    FROM IDDPAC PAC,
    (
        SELECT AVG(TA.TAD) TAD
        FROM
        (
            SELECT
            TEXT_TO_NUMBER ( PAG.TEXTO ) TAD
            FROM IDDPAG PAG, DATE D
            WHERE TRIM  ( PAG.DGP )='AH'
            AND PAG.ID=T.ID
            AND PAG.FECHA=D.OMI
            AND D.TIME_DATE::DATE BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01'
            AND DATE '2012-12-31'
            ORDER BY PAG.FECHA DESC LIMIT 3
        ) TA
    ) T
    WHERE PAC.CENTRO='10040110' AND T.ID = PAC.ID
    GROUP BY PAC.CENTRO , PAC.ID
)
A
WHERE T.TAD < 90
GROUP BY CENTRO
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  falta una entrada para la tabla «t» en la cláusula FROM
LINE 31:             AND PAG.ID=T.ID
                                ^
********** Error **********
```

Translation:

```
ERROR:  missing an entry for the table «t» in the clause FROM
LINE 31:             AND PAG.ID=T.ID
                                ^
********** Error **********
```

Comment: . . Your non-working query doesn't really help understand the problem.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: The non-working query is perfectly sufficient for me to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the average of the last three values, use `row_number()` to enumerate the values.  Then choose the last three and take the average.  This gives you the patient level information:

```
    SELECT PAC.CENTRO, PAG.ID, AVG(TA.TAD) AS TAD
    FROM (SELECT PAG.ID, TEXT_TO_NUMBER ( PAG.TEXTO ) as TAD,
                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PAG.ID ORDER BY D.TIME_DATE DESC) as seqnum
          FROM IDDPAG PAG JOIN
               DATE D
               ON PAG.FECHA = D.OMI JOIN
               IDDPAC PAC
               ON PAC.ID = PAG.ID
          WHERE TRIM  ( PAG.DGP )='AH' AND
                D.TIME_DATE::DATE BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01' AND DATE '2012-12-31'
         ) TA
    WHERE SEQNUM <= 3
    GROUP BY PAC.CENTRO, PAD.ID
    HAVING AVG(TA.TAD) < 90;
```

The count by `centro` would just be:

```
  SELECT CENTRO, COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT PAC.CENTRO, PAG.ID, AVG(TA.TAD) AS TAD
        FROM (SELECT PAG.ID, TEXT_TO_NUMBER ( PAG.TEXTO ) as TAD,
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PAG.ID ORDER BY D.TIME_DATE DESC) as seqnum
              FROM IDDPAG PAG JOIN
                   DATE D
                   ON PAG.FECHA = D.OMI JOIN
                   IDDPAC PAC
                   ON PAC.ID = PAG.ID
              WHERE TRIM  ( PAG.DGP )='AH' AND
                    D.TIME_DATE::DATE BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01' AND DATE '2012-12-31'
             ) TA
        WHERE SEQNUM <= 3
        GROUP BY PAC.CENTRO, PAD.ID
        HAVING AVG(TA.TAD) < 90
       ) TA
  GROUP BY CENTRO;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, exactly as the error indicates, that 'T' is not defined in the place it is requested.  Your error is in the innermost  subquery:

```
        SELECT
        TEXT_TO_NUMBER ( PAG.TEXTO ) TAD
        FROM IDDPAG PAG, DATE D
        WHERE TRIM  ( PAG.DGP )='AH'
        AND PAG.ID=T.ID
        AND PAG.FECHA=D.OMI
        AND D.TIME_DATE::DATE BETWEEN DATE '2012-01-01'
        AND DATE '2012-12-31'
        ORDER BY PAG.FECHA DESC LIMIT 3
```

But there is no `T` defined here to be used in the `PAG.ID=T.ID` portion of your `WHERE` clause. Did you mean to join on a table called `T`? Or did you mean to use `D.ID` instead?

Comment: @Antonio: I offered some suggestions. I don't know exactly what you're trying to do, so I can't tell you precisely how to fix it. But you're trying to compare to a table that doesn't exist.  First, get your subquery working without everything else. Once that's working, plug it into your larger query.